# Spark dataframe combine multiple rows into one with same key

Tags: pyspark

i have a data in spark DF which looks like this

[image]

the deseired ouput is combining all the not null values into one row with the same key combination

note: the dataframe size is very big

Thank you,
Rahul

Comment: Is it guaranteed that only one non-null value exists for each column-key combination?

Comment: @ARCrow not actually , it can have multiple rows

Comment: So what are the criteria for choosing a value for "energy" column if the energy column has multiple values for an id-name pair?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = (
    df
    .groupBy('id', 'name')
    .agg(
        f.collect_set(f.col('energy')).alias('energy'), 
        f.collect_set(f.col('mass')).alias('mass'),
        f.collect_set(f.col('volume')).alias('volume'),
        f.collect_set(f.col('weight')).alias('weight')
    )
    .select(
        f.expr('filter(energy, element -> element is not null)')[0].alias('energy'),
        f.expr('filter(mass, element -> element is not null)')[0].alias('mass'),
        f.expr('filter(volume, element -> element is not null)')[0].alias('volume'),
        f.expr('filter(weight, element -> element is not null)')[0].alias('weight'),
        'id', 'name'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as ARCrow asked that if you want expect only one non null value or any non null value is acceptable then you can use below code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy("id","name").agg(F.first("energy",True),F.first("mass",True),F.first("volume",True),F.first("weight",True)).show()
```

Here I am just grouping on required keys and picking first non null value in that group